# working on datepicker and trying to disable sunday mondays on datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

i am new at js and jquery
working on datepicker and trying to disable sunday mondays on datepicker
i tried before beforeShowDay function but its not working
got solution on stack but it's not working 
expert get me out this?

here is my js

```
<script>

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
var day = date.getDay();
return [day != 0,''];
}
})​​​​​;​
</script>
```

here is html body

```
<input id="#datepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: yes I am using jquery-ui datepicker

Comment: Did the answer posted by me helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below, as well you need to initialize datepicker in `document.ready` function

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        // 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday
        return [date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1 ? false : true];
    }
})​​​​​;​
```

Working example is below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      // 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday
      return [date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1 ? false : true];
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```